# Docker for Windows - Cannot run docker-compose up without getting "does not exist" or "login" errors

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

FYI - This all works when run on a Mac, but I am wanting to run on Windows.

I am running the following commands from IntelliJ terminal:

> 1 - `docker login` (logging in with my credentials and getting the success message)
>
> 2 - `docker-compose up` (to create and start the container)

However upon running the second command, I am greeted with:

> Pulling marklogic (xxxxxxx:latest)...
>   ERROR: pull access denied for ..., repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

I have searched the forums and found nothing to explain what is going wrong, other than my colleagues explanation that Windows is rubbish.

Any help would be appreciated.

Some extra info:

```
docker -v
Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a96
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well pressassociation/faux-uds-marklogic isn't in DockerHub, so I guess you have to build that first yourself, or make sure your are pointing at an internal company repository that someone else has pushed the image to.

Perhaps it works on the Mac because a docker login has been made to an internal registry before running the docker-compose up ?

Comment: I think perhaps I haven't been granted access to the necessary repo yet. I will check that and get back to you if things aren't working still.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use your own registry (docker-registry.xxx) in your project?

Comment: Not that I can see. There is a `docker-compose.yaml` file with various configuration options in for Hazelcast, MarkLogic, linking to other repos that are required to stand the stack up etc